# Hide a header name in WKWebView iOS

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, wkwebview

I want to hide or remove the header of a webpage in `WKWebview` in iOS.

My header name should be "HeaderWrapper". I tried removing it using the below code but nothing happens. Any help would be appreciated.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var webView: WKWebView!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let url = URL(string: "https://www.homepagename.com")
        let request = URLRequest(url: url!)

        webView.load(request)
        }

    func webView(webView: WKWebView,didFinishNavigation navigation: WKNavigation){

           webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.querySelector('.HeaderWrapper').remove();", completionHandler: { (response, error) -> Void in

           })
       }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you set up the navigationdelegate for the WKWebView, is this method called? And what does the error say?

Comment: No is navigationdelegate lika a class? Is it possible to read errors you say?

Comment: Delegates are a basic concept in many languages, including Swift. I highly recommend that you read about them. In your case, the viewcontroller for your webview should be the navigationdelegate and have the code in your question.

Comment: This is a really good tutorial how to use `WKWebView`: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/articles/112/the-ultimate-guide-to-wkwebview

Comment: Yes I have read that guide couple of times, its a good guide.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else have a similar problem, this was my final solution with inspiration from Koen above. My only problem was that I hoped it to kill the header before it was appearing for the users. But this solution will not do that.

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate {

  @IBOutlet weak var webView: WKWebView!

  override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let url = URL(string: "https://www.homepagename.com")
        let request = URLRequest(url: url!)

        webView.navigationDelegate = self
        webView.load(request)
    }

func webView(_ webView: WKWebView,didFinish navigation: WKNavigation) {
        webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.querySelector('.HeaderWrapper').remove();",
        completionHandler: { (response, error) -> Void in

        })
    }
}
```

Comment: See my updated answer that hides the webview until the script is executed. If that works for you, please mark it as the accepted answer, see also here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Will this code really work? When I run it, the header first shows up before it is terminated.

Answer (score -1):

You are missing the `navigationDelegate`. Change your code to:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var webView: WKWebView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        webView.isHidden = true
        let url = URL(string: "https://www.homepagename.com")
        let request = URLRequest(url: url!)

        webView.navigationDelegate = self
        webView.load(request)
    }

    func webView(webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation) {
        webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.querySelector('.HeaderWrapper').remove();", 
        completionHandler: { (response, error) -> Void in
            webView.isHidden = false
        })
    }
}
```